# How to print out two queries in one table?

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I have two queries in a form. I print out the results like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading1</th>
      <th>Heading2</th>
      <th>Heading3</th>
      <th>Heading4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($result1 as $row1) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column1"]); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column2"]); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column3"]); ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?> </tr>


       <tr> <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2) : ?>
            <td><?php echo escape($row2["Column4"]); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to present each result in a different column. But the result from the second query ("Column4") seems to be presented in a second table (??). It's not echoed next to the other columns, but below:
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR7kd.png)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How many rows in query2 for each row in query1? It strikes me that the queries could be combined which would make things clearer, though it's impossible to be sure without seeing the queries.

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.SubTerm = table2.name";


  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.GenericTerm = table2.name";



They're both querying the same tables but are joined differently. Table1 consists only out of IDs (since both columns are foreign keys to the same table) and Table2 includes the corresponding names for the IDs.

Comment: Why, then, don't you put both JOINs in the same query? "select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.subterm = table2.name left join table2 on table1.genericterm = table2.name" or something like that. I'd expect you to JOIN on table2.id rather than table2.name, but I don't know your column names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
<?php endforeach; ?> </tr>


       <tr> <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2) : ?>
```

into

```
 <?php endforeach; ?> 
 <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2) : ?>
```

You have begun another row ('tr' tag closed and re-opened).

Comment: oh you're right! However it's not changing anything except that the first row of Column 4 is somehow in the last row of the other columns (I don't know how to properly explain that but basically it just moved one row up) I don't know why this is

Comment: That's I understood from your image :P Anyway if you have more results from queries you'll have only a row with N+M cols...

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix...

I have removed the things that are causing it to echo on next line

Now this will work...

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading1</th>
      <th>Heading2</th>
      <th>Heading3</th>
      <th>Heading4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($result1 as $row1) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column1"]); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column2"]); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo escape($row1["Column3"]); ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?> 


        <?php foreach ($result2 as $row2) : ?>
            <td><?php echo escape($row2["Column4"]); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason it's not changing anything except that the first row of Column 4 is somehow in the last row of the other columns (I don't know how to properly explain that but basically it just moved one row up) I don't know why this is